# Any API key for accessing Credit Memo details in Magento?

Tags: php, api, magento

I am working on Magento Quick book project. I am want to get Credit Memo details from the Magento DB using API. Please anyone tell me, is there any key available for getting Credit Memo details or any other solution available for getting Credit Memo details from the Credit memo table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API for credit memo isn't available yet.You can try to create your own API for this using next [article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/web_services/custom_api_complete_example) or wait while credit memo API become available.

Comment: Btw, as I know it will be available in EE 1.11.1.